# What's wrong with my disp command?

Tags: matlab

I want to generate a series QR codes for my experiments, by using the QR code generator [enter link description here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49808-qr-code-generator-1-1-based-on-zxing?focused=7172243&tab=example). Then I tried to use the code as followed:

```
%importtool import qrTEST
d=table2cell(qrTEST)
for i=1:numel(d)
mas=disp(d{i})
qr = qrcode_gen(mas,'size',97,'QuietZone',20)
fExample6 = figure
colormap(gray)
imagesc(qr)
axis image
saveas(gcf,disp(d{i}).JPG)
end
```

Then I get an error massage: 
Error using disp 
Too many output arguments.

Why do I get this error? Could somebody help me to improve it? How should I write the code to import the .csv file instead of using import tool?

Thank you!

I don't know how to add the attach file to the questions. So here I give it as a text.

```
PDA_H0.25_1
PDA_H0.25_2
PDA_H0.25_3
PDA_H0.5_1
PDA_H0.5_2
PDA_H0.5_3
PDA_H0.75_1
PDA_H0.75_2
PDA_H0.75_3
```

Comment: directly concatenate it with .jpg i.e. `[d{i},'.JPG']`

Comment: @SardarUsama do you mean the name in the saves step? I changed it as you suggested, but still get the same error. I just tried mas=disp(d{i}), and I get the same error. I guess this code cause the problem.

Comment: I don't see that `disp` has a return value from the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html)

Comment: @beaker I saved the text as windows cvs file, and imported by the import tool. If I don't use table2cell to convert it, then disp command shows no value.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with 'disp'? As beaker said it has no outputs, it has only a side effect to show the value on the screen.

Comment: `disp` only displays the data. Use `saveas(gcf, [d{i} '.JPG'])` to concatenate the string.

Comment: @pacta_sunt_servanda  I want to generate a QR code according to each text in each row, e.g. PDA_H0.25_1. So I thought I can use disp to show the text, as an input for generating the QR code (an input for 'qrcode_gen' call). So that's why I write 'mas=disp(d{i})'. Now I know 'disp' can't be used as an input. So which one should i use? I have tried 'sprintf' and 'fprintf'. Neither of them works.

Comment: @beaker So if I want to define the mas as one of the text content, e.g. PDA_H0.25_1. How should I achieve it? Thx!!

Comment: `mas  = d{i};` `d{i}` is a character array already. You don't want to *show* the text, you want to assign it to a variable. Or you could just use `d{i}` instead of `mas`.

Comment: @beaker Oh it works!!! SO great! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Error using disp Too many output arguments.* means exactly what it says.
`disp()` does not produce an output argument, and you are trying to catch an output argument `mas` by writing `mas=disp(d{i})`

Furthermore this might solve your problems
`qr = qrcode_gen(d{i} ,'size',97,'QuietZone',20)`

Comment: So what if I want to show the text content in mas, e.g. PDA_H0.25_1, how should I write the code?

Comment: I solve it. thanks anyway! i have no idea why I got downvotes. maybe my level is too low... :(

Comment: hehe I'm glad you solved it! I gave an upvote ;)
I think it's ok when people give a downvote, but not ok when they don't comment on why the gave the downvote! I suggest you either post an answer and accept it or accept my answer, so that your question is closed!